# how to return struct variable from a function in c programming?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I created a local structure student c inside the function, how to return student c from function to the the student d in the main fuction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct student
{
     char name[10];
}a,b;
struct student name(struct student *ptr)
{
    struct student c; 
    strcpy(c.name,ptr->name);
    return c.name;    //error
}
int main()
{
    printf("enter name");
    scanf("%c",&a.name);
    b.name=name (&a.name);   //error
    printf("%c",b.name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given a function that returns an integer, how do you return the integer?  `int i = 37; return i;`? And you call it `int j; …; j = intfunc(29);` or similar; or `int k = 31; int j = intptrfunc(&k);`, etc. So, you return a structure the same way: `struct student c; …initialization…; return c;`. How do you assign the structure in the call: `struct student b; …; b = name(&a);` (which is also how you pass a pointer to the structure).  You don't specify the elements of the structure; you specify the structure variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question:

> how to return struct variable from a function in c programming?

does not match your code.

In your code you try to return a **single struct member** (i.e. `c.name`) but not the whole struct. Since the struct member is a char array (to be used as a string it seems) you get a lot of errors because i C you can't assign string variables (aka char array variables) using the `=` operator.

If you really wanted to return a struct simply do:

```
struct student name(struct student *ptr)
{
    struct student c; 
    strcpy(c.name,ptr->name);
    return c;    // Just use c instead of c.name;
}
```

and the call from `main` would be:

```
b = name(&a);
```

BTW:

```
scanf("%c",&a.name);
```

is wrong. I assume you want to read a word - not just a character - so `%s` is the specifier to use. Like: `scanf("%9s", a.name);`

Notice that `scanf` with `%s` only allows scan of 1 word. As a name can be several words you may want to use `fgets` instead.

This also applies to the `printf`, i.e. use `%s` instead of `%c`